# Start server with GUI (kde/gnome) to terminal by default

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

I've set up home server, which doesn't have to be as powerful as other servers, so I decided to install GUI because of applications that are alternatives to classical GUI applications in headless version requires more skill/knowledge. However, I don't want server to run GUI always at start (which gnome-desktop package does). I need some configuration in KDE/gnome/xfce (haven't decided) that doesn't start GUI after each start (e.g is required to type *startx* or equivalent command to start GUI)

(off topic: can you also recommend good remote-administration with GUI transport ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change default init level in **/etc/inittab** to level 3 instead of 5 (with GUI).

The line you need to change is:

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

To start gui run as superuser:

```
init 5
```